# svyglm function how to change the catergoircal variable in the summary

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I am using the svyglm function to run a regression model. I have an interaction term which is a categorical variable of yes and no. The regression model is showing the estimates for no but I would like to analyse the yes. I was wondering how I can do that? Thanks for your help!

This is an image of the dataset covid.surveydesgin = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNxgx.png)

The Data for this column is just Yes/No for 3000 row, I am unable to share the whole dataset.

YES =  692
NO = 2996

I tried to re-level using fct_relevel() and lapply() but that didn't work, any suggestions would be really appreciated.

`Regression1<-svyglm(formula = ca_scghq1_dv~(None+Average+Above_Average+Astronomical)*ca_furlough, design = covid.surveydesgin)`
`summary(Regression1)`

`Call: svyglm(formula = ca_scghq1_dv ~ (None + Average + Above_Average +  Astronomical) * ca_furlough, design = covid.surveydesgin)`

```
Coefficients:
                                Estimate |Std. Error |t value |Pr(>|t|) |   
(Intercept)                      12.2457     0.5321  23.012  < 2e-16 ***|
   

|ca_furloughNo                     |0.5957    | 0.5731  | 1.039  |0.29906  |  
|NoneTRUE:ca_furloughNo           |-1.4100     |0.9212  |-1.531  |0.12644  |  
|AverageTRUE:ca_furloughNo         |1.7233     |1.3013   |1.324  |0.18596  |  
|Above_AverageTRUE:ca_furloughNo   |0.2059     |1.6990   |0.121  |0.90357  |  
|AstronomicalTRUE:ca_furloughNo    |1.8439     |2.2777   |0.810  |0.41855  |
```

Comment: We need more information about data. Could you post it?

Comment: I am unable to post the data, but what information would be helpful?

Comment: How do you define covid.surveydesgin?

Comment: I have added a summary of the data, hope that's helpful. Thanks so much for your help!